# How can I display File creation date in output when converting from XML to txt file using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I am trying to display the text file creation date in the output while converting an XML file to a Text file. Is there any way to display that information dynamically? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current-dateTime()` is a function you can call to find the dateTime is run. If you want to read information from the file system then you need http://expath.org/spec/file#pr.last-modified

Comment: Thank you Martin..But wouldn't that just return the current date from the system? I am looking for the date and time the text file is created from an XMl via XSLT. Thank you for you prompt reply.

Comment: If your XSLT creates that file, I am not sure which other value you want than the dateTime the XSLT is called. If you want to read out information from the file system, then I don't think XSLTcan do it without an extension like the EXPath file module.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin. I tried current-dateTime() and it is indeed giving me the file creation date which is what I wanted. I was thinking that this command would just fetch the current date from the system. Thank you so much : )

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for

```
<xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response Friedemann..But wouldn't that just return the current date from the system? I am looking for the date and time the text file is created from an XMl via XSLT.